# Postgres : `exec': connection is closed (PG::ConnectionBad) (ruby not rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am pg gem in ruby ( I am not using rails at all, this just ruby), when I call a select statement it works :

```
res_t = @pg_conn.exec("SELECT * FROM brcmanager.\"Users\" limit 2;")
```

but when I try to do it in a loop to use more than one table, using an array of tables :

```
array_table_names.each { |x| 
 res_t = @pg_conn.exec("SELECT * FROM brcmanager.\"#{x}\" limit 2;")
```

I got :

```
brc_migration_match_data.rb:69:in `exec': connection is closed (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe there's another part that is closing the connection?

Comment: what are array_table_names?